# Spring Data JPA findAll() or findbyId() return wrong value in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently struggling with findAll() method when I try to retrieve data from SQL Server
here are my code:

Alien:

```
 @Entity
public class Alien {
    @Id
    private String aid;
    private String name;
    private String tech;
```

AlienController:

```
@Controller
public class AlienController {

@Autowired
AlienRepository repo;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "home.jsp";
}
@RequestMapping("/getAliens")
@ResponseBody
public String getAlien() {
    return repo.findAll().toString();
  }
}
```

Repository

```
public interface AlienRepository extends CrudRepository<Alien, String>{

}
```

And my problem is whenever I try to retrieve all the Aliens in my DB I usually got this value

```
[com.example.demo.model.Alien@1f012f9c, com.example.demo.model.Alien@553ee2df, com.example.demo.model.Alien@67c572ce]
```

Usually it has to return the value of the Alien like aid , name and tech but all I got is this

Comment: Try overriding toString method in Alien class. And change return type of getAlien() method to List<Alien> unless you don't want List type to be returned.

Comment: it actually returns instances of Alien, but, as Pavan pointed out, since you didn't override the toString method, you get the implementation it overrides from Object, which means you are printing the reference

Comment: Are you using spring-boot or spring-mvc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value `com.example.demo.model.Alien@1f012f9c` is returned by default implementaion of `toString()` method.

Add `toString()` you Alien class.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Alien {

  @Id
  private String aid;
  private String name;
  private String tech;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Alien{" +
            "aid='" + aid + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", tech='" + tech + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data as `List<Alien>` and use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` to get json response

```
  @RequestMapping("/getAliens", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseBody
  public List<Alien> getAlien() {
    return repo.findAll();
  }
```

Or define toString method in `Alien` class if you want to return list as string